# Как реализовать таймер в bash?

Tags: bash

У меня есть секундомер сделанный в скрипт баше, но я не знаю как сделать, чтоб он работал всего 20сек и показывал время до окончания скрипта

main:

```
let start_time="$(date +%s)";
     
    function main(){
      echo "Welcome to my timer"
      start_timer
      exit 0
    }
     
    function start_timer(){
      while [ 1 ];
      do
        let current_time="$(date +%s)"
        let seconds=$current_time-$start_time;
     
        echo -en "\r                                        \r"
        printf "Timer: %02d:%02d:%02d:%02d" "$((seconds/86400))" "$((seconds/3600%24))" "$((seconds/60%60))" "$((seconds%60))" 
        sleep 1;
      done
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function start_timer(){
#Получаем переменную таймер, если не поступила, устанавливаем в 20
    timer=${1:-20}   
#Меняем цикл на количество шагов таймера
    for ((i=${timer};i>=0;i--)); do
          let current_time="$(date +%s)"
          let seconds=$current_time-$start_time
          printf "\rTimer: %02d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n" "$((seconds/86400))" "$((seconds/3600%24))" "$((seconds/60%60))" "$((seconds%60))"
#Печатаем таймер, возвращаем каретку и один backspace
          printf "\rОсталось работать: %02d\r\b" $i
          sleep 1
    done;
}
```

Вывод:

```
#start_timer
>>Timer: 00:00:00:01
>>Осталось работать: 19

#start_timer 10
>>Timer: 00:00:00:01
>>Осталось работать: 09
```

Answer (score 2):

В bash'е есть стандартная переменная `$SECONDS` она показывает время(в сек.) от начала скрипта, попробуйте такой скрипт:

```
$ cat timer
#!/bin/bash

echo $SECONDS
sleep 20
echo $SECONDS

$ ./timer 
0
20
```

Дальше как-то так:

```
n=20
while true; do
    sleep 1
    echo "осталось $((n-SECONDS)) секунд"
done
```

Результат:

```
осталось 19 секунд
осталось 18 секунд
осталось 17 секунд
осталось 16 секунд
осталось 15 секунд
осталось 14 секунд
...
```